# Constructing a parabola from two coordinate values and a peak height.

Tags: graphing-functions, quadratics

I am trying to create a parabola function that mimics projectile trajectory. It will input the following:

- 2 xy coordinates (the starting projectile position and the landing projectile position)
- Height of the throw

And will output the following:

- A parabola where the turning point is at the height.
- The parabola should also intersect the starting and ending throwing positions.

How can I go about doing this?

I attached a picture to illustrate what I am trying to do.

[image]

So in this case. The inputs will be (-1, 1), (1, 3.5) and 4 as the height of the throw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any point $(x, y)$ on a parabola with vertex $(h, k)$, we have the proportion $(x-h)^2\propto(y-k)$, or $|x-h|\propto\sqrt{|y-k|}$.  Since we know what $y_1$, $y_2$ and $k$ are, we can find some possibilities for $h$.

We have:  $|x_1 - h| \propto \sqrt{|y_1-k|}$ and $|x_2 - h| \propto \sqrt{|y_2-k|}$.  This then gives two possibilities:  $x_1-h$ has the opposite sign of $x_2-h$, or they have the same sign.  We'll cover the first, first, assuming WLOG that $x_2>x_1$.

We know that $x_2 - h + h - x_1 = x_2 - x_1$; Also, that $h$ will be, proportionally, $|x_1 - h| / (x_2 - x_1)$ along that part.  But that's $|x_1 - h| / \left(|x_1-h| + |x_2-h|\right)$, and we can calculate all those.  $$t=\frac{\sqrt{|y_1-k|}}{\sqrt{|y_1-k|}+\sqrt{|y_2-k|}}$$
$$h = (1-t)x_1+tx_2$$
For us, this gives $$t=\frac{2}{2+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{8-2\sqrt{6}}{5}\approx0.62$$ and $$h=\frac{11-4\sqrt{6}}{5}\approx 0.24$$
Which, ultimately, gives us the parabola
$$y=-\frac{11+4\sqrt{6}}{8}x^2+\frac{5}{4}x+\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{29}{8}$$

In the same fashion we can use

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{|y_1-k|}}{\sqrt{|y_1-k|}-\sqrt{|y_2-k|}}$$
to get 
$$t=\frac{2}{2-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{8+2\sqrt{6}}{5}\approx2.58$$
$$h=\frac{11+4\sqrt{6}}{5}\approx 4.16$$
$$y=-\frac{11-4\sqrt{6}}{8}x^2+\frac{5}{4}x-\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{29}{8}$$

Here those are graphed.  The narrower one uses the first $t$ and $h$.

[image: Two parabolas through two points, with a given height]

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem (surprisingly enough) by solving a system of linear equations. The second degree polynomial that gives rise to the parabola will be of the form 
$$f(x) =A x^2 + B x + C.$$
To get the parabola you want we need to solve $A$, $B$ and $C$. If you set three points of the parabola, say $(x_1,y_1)$, $(x_2,y_2)$ and $(x_3,y_3)$, you are in fact telling the value of the polynomial $f$ in three points; $f(x_1) = y_1$ etc. This means that by putting the values in $f$ you get three linear equations with three unknowns, namely $A$, $B$ and $C$:
$$
\begin{cases}
 A x_1^2 + Bx_1 + C = y_1 \\
A x_2^2 + Bx_2 + C = y_2 \\
A x_3^2 + Bx_3 + C = y_3 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Solve for $A$, $B$ and $C$ as in linear algebra and you have your parabola.

Also, you can use similar methods to [share secrets.](http://datagenetics.com/blog/november22012/index.html)

Comment: Is it possible to translate this equation into 3 dimensional space?

Comment: @Ogen It doesn't sound impossible... I would guess that if you have a polynomial of two variables $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, with degree $n$, (so $P(x,y) = \sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i y^{n-i}$ or something), it might suffice to know $n+1$ points on the graph to fix the function, but I can't promise anything. (I'm not immediately sure if all the linear equations will be necessarily independent...)

Comment: Hang on a second - we don't have $x_3$; we have the height of the peak but not its location...

Comment: Imagine if the starting and ending locations of the throw are xyz coords instead of xy coords

Comment: @DanUznanski Whoops, you are correct. I read the question too quickly. (And stared at the picture.) If we know only the height and nothing of the location (and the two other points have different heights), there are at least two different solutions. (Looking at the question's picture, the other parabola lies such that the highest point is to the right of the two red dots.) I'd claim that if the highest point is between the two known points, you will have a unique answer... This requires a moments thought.

Comment: Oh, I know.  You know that the x distance to the peak is proportional to the square root of the y distance to the peak.

Comment: Can't think of an elegant solution on the spot, but for a polynomial $f(x) = Ax^2 + Bx + C$ the maximum will be obtained at the point $x_0 = -\frac{B}{2A}$. You can plot this as the 'missing' data point. The problem is that now you no longer get a linear system of equations, so the solution to that is not so mechanical any more...

Comment: what other piece of information from the user would make this question a lot easier?

Comment: So you have, for this one: $t = \sqrt{4}/(\sqrt{4} + \sqrt{3/2})$;  $x_3 = -1 * (1-t) + 1*t$

Comment: And in general:  $t = \sqrt{|y_3-y_1|}/(\sqrt{|y_3-y1|}+\sqrt{|y_3-y_2|})$; $x_3 = x_1(1-t)+x_2t$

Comment: If the highest point is between the two given points, you could do the following. Use the first two points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ as before to generate a system of linear equations. This system will have 3 variables and 2 equations, so you will not find a unique solution. You will, however, find a family of solutions parametrised by some real number, say $t$. This family will look something like $$f_t(x) = (3-t)x^2 + (2t) -1.$$ Now you calculate (via e.g. differential) the maximum of such a polynomial. This will depend on $t$ and now you can solve for which $t$ you get the wanted height.

Comment: @Ogen, I use my answer in 3D space by treating $x$, $y$, and $z$ as parametric functions of $t$ on the range [0, 1]. Linearly interpolate $x$ and $z$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$ and $z_1$ to $z_2$. For $y(t)$, use $y1 + at^2+bt$, with $a$ and $b$ defined as in my answer. Works great for animating parabolic jumps up/down between platforms in 3D games.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at answering a question on math.stackexchange, so if I fall short of best form, please provide suggestions for improving the answer.

Given a launch point at $(x_1, y_1)$, a landing point at $(x_2, y_2)$, and a maximum altitude $k$, we want the equation for a parabola, $y=ax^2+bx+c$ , opening downward that includes those points and has its vertex at $(h,k)$.

We note that the problem can be solved with a parabola where $(x1,y1) = (0,0)$ by translation to the origin, and with a parabola where $x2=1$ by scaling in the x axis. We also note that $0<h<1$. As the parabola includes the origin, we know that $c=0$.

As we have reduced the problem to finding $a$ and $b$ for a parabola defined by $y=ax^2+b$, we have

[1] $y_2 = a \cdot 1^2 + b \cdot 1 = a + b$

and

[2] $k=ah^2+bh$

as $y' = 2ax+b$, we have

[3] $0=2ah+b$

This provides three equations in three unknowns $a,b,h$, which is determined, but Equation 2 is non-linear. This is not fatal, but it can be problematic depending upon the order in which we eliminate unknowns by substitution.

We can transform the problem into a system of three linear equations, however, by taking note that the parabola is symmetrical around the line $x=h$. The parabola contains $(1,y_2)$. Thus, it contains $(h+(1-h), y_2)$. As $x=h$ is the line of symmetry, this means the parabola also contains $(h-(1-h), y_2)$, or $(2h-1, y_2)$. So, we also have

[4] $y_2=a(2h-1)^2+b(2h-1)$

Expanding the terms in [4] produces

[5] $y_2 = 4ah^2-4ah+a+2bh-b$

Multiplying [2] by four and subtracting the product from [5], we eliminate the non-linear term:

[6] $4k-y_2 = 4ah-a+2bh+b$

[1], [3], and [6] are a system of linear equations in three unknowns, and can be solved by substitution, yielding

$$b = 2k +2\sqrt{k^2-ky_2}$$
$$a=y_2-b$$
$$h=-b/2a$$

Note that, if $0<k$ and $y_2<k$, which would be the case in any physical scenario where an object was launched *upward* from the origin to a maximum height of $y=k$, and falling back *downward* to a height of $y=y_2$, this solution guarantees that $a\ne0$, so $h$ is always defined.